# Regular expression for allow only numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to check the following with regular expression

```
{Today,Format}
```

Today - will be remains as it is.
In the place of Format, we can allow the digits from 0 to 12.

for example: we have to allow

```
{Today,0}
{Today,1}
{Today,2}
...
{Today,12}
```

and also have to allow

```
{Today,}
{Today,Format}
```

Please help me and also refer me to some site to develop my regular expression skills.

Comment: Just FYI, 'regex' is a far more common tag than 'regular-expression' or similar.

Answer (score 18):

```
\{Today,(\d|1[012]|Format)?\}
```

Meaning:

- Open curly brace;
- 'Today,';
- Optionally one of the following: a digit (0-9), 1 followed by 0, 1 or 2 (10,11,12), 'Format'; and then
- Close curly brace.

As for resources I can recommend [this site on regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and the book [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124).

Answer (score 4):

[txt2re.com](http://txt2re.com/) is a brilliant web-based regex generator...

Answer (score 0):

You might also find this [list of regular expression software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_regular_expression_software) quite useful. [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) is my favorite.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/) is a short cheat sheet to regex.